# railsでカラムの合計値を表示したい　(初歩的な質問)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

priceカラムにある数値を合計し、表示したいと考えていますがエラーが出続けうまくいきません。モデル内には以下のようなコードを書き込んであるのですがどう変更すればよいでしょうか。
初歩的な質問で申し訳ないですがよろしくお願いいたします。

```
def sumprice
User.sum(:Price)
end

sumprice
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

やりたいことを想像するにこうでしょうか。

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #インスタンスメソッドではなくクラスメソッドのほうが適切でしょう
  def self.sumprice  
    sum(:price)
    #User.sumでもかまいません
    #カラム名(フィールド名)は大文字使ってもいいですが、普通小文字の方がよいです
  end
end
```

呼び出すときは

```
User.sumprice # => 123
```

Comment: 細かい部分にもご指摘をいただきありがとうございます。
問題も解決し表示されるようになりました。回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

> エラーが出続けうまくいきません

具体的なエラーの内容を書き込まないと、エラーの原因が推測できません。
「エラーが出ます」と一言に言っても、数え切れないぐらい様々なケースがあるので。
一番良いのはエラーメッセージとスタックトレースを載せてもらうことです。

ちなみに、手元のプロジェクトを使うとこんな感じで合計値を求めることができました。（DBはPostgres）

```
> Book.sum(:price) 
   (0.5ms)  SELECT SUM("books"."price") AS sum_id FROM "books"
=> 7000
```

おそらくコード自体は問題がなさそうなので、原因は他の部分にありそうです。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。今後気をつけます。
原因に関してはコードを用いさせていただいたところviewにあることがわかり解決いたしました。ご丁寧に回答いただきありがとうございました。